# Out-Gridview quick filter searches not allowing spaces

Tags: powershell, filter, typing, out-gridview

I'm using `Out-GridView` for PowerShell. Everything seems to work out fine, with the notable exception that *Quick Filter* searches do not allow for spaces to be typed in between multiple words. Unfortunately this is exactly what is advertised on its docs.microsoft utility website:

> Search for multiple words. To search for multiple words in the table,
> type the words separated by spaces. Out-GridView displays rows that
> include all the words (logical AND).

I've tried loading Out-GridView with a few variations (such as the standard `Get-Process`) but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Edited: I actually discovered that it was due to the differences between running Gridview through PowerShell and PowerShell ISE; the problem only manifested when I was running it through ISE. Face-plant worthy.

Comment: I've always had this issue on multiple devices. Not really a solution but you can type two words without spaces and then go back and insert a space into the string, it seems to only be when the space is at the end of the string it doesn't permit it.

Comment: I don't see the symptom in Windows PowerShell v5.1.18362.752, which comes with Windows 10 version 1909. I do see the symptom in PowerShell [Core] v7.0, however. Please add details about your environment to the question.

Comment: See: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13528

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I use a corporate machine so I do not have the ability to install PowerShell's Graphical Tools.

Comment: I actually discovered that it was due to the differences between running Gridview through PowerShell and PowerShell ISE; the problem only manifested when I was running it through ISE. Face-plant worthy.